# OnChangeEvent in categories and subcategories

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I am new to php. I am getting problem in onchange event in select option ...if I change the
categories the whole form is getting submitted instead of on change the value of categories1.

The problem in onchange event in `onchange="myform.submit()"`.

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="getsearch.php"> 
        <table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="0px" align="center"> 
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="3" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:20px">Search</td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
            <td>Name</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="name" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Email</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="email" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Phone</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="phone" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr> 
                <td>categories</td> 
                <td><select name="first" onchange="myform.submit()">
                    <option value="">select the category</option>
                    <?php 
                            $sql="select *from first_category";
                            $res=mysql_query($sql);
                            echo $res;
                            if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
                            {
                                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
                                    {
                                        if(isset($_POST["first"]) AND $_POST["first"]==$row["first_id"])
                                        $select ="selected='selected'";
                                        else
                                        $select='';
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row["first_id"].'" '.$select.'>'.$row["category_name"].'</option>';
                                    }

                                    }
                        ?>
                </select></td> 

            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>categories1</td> 
                <td><select name="second">
                        <option value="">select the second category</option>
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($_POST["first"]))
                            {

                                $sql="select *from second_category where first_id=".intval($_POST["first"]);
                                $res=mysql_query($sql);
                                echo $res;
                                if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
                                {
                                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row["second_id"].'">'.$row["second_categoryname"].'</option>';
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                                ?>
                                    </select></td> 

            </tr> 
            <center><tr >
                    <td valign="middle"><input type="submit" value="Search" id="hi" name="hi" /></td> 
            </tr></center>

        </table>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Of course the form should be submitted because you called myform.submit. What do you want to do instead of that? Please make your question clear.

Also, take note of the first comment.

Comment: I think he wants the second select field to be filled dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix php and javascript. PHP is executed on the server-side, you can not call it by changing a select or something like that (except via Ajax).

So if you really want to have this behavior, you can either dump your datas into a javascript object and then iterate over that to fill the second select dynamically or implement it via Ajax. For this: call an extra php script, which is just returning the correct values and fill them via javascript. You can find a good tutorial how to solve that with jQuery over here: http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html